# what's the difference between rsenc and comm.RSDecoder in Matlab

Tags: matlab, reed-solomon

Does there anyone know the difference between these two RS code function?

After i call the two function, rsdec can correct errors but other one can't.

If I want to encode [2 1 4 2] by RS,rsdec can correct errors but comm.RSDecoder still not to do that.

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rsdec works only for 'n symbols' Rs(7,3)  n=7
but comm.rsdec  can be able to solve 10^i bits.  a*n symbol values.